# access mule http endpoint deployed in tomcat

Tags: web-services, soap, mule

I have developed a SOAP webservice in mule, which has the endpoint configured as say

for e.g. 
        http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:7001/helloService"
            doc:name="HTTP"

It is deployed as a WAR file in tomcat server. Am able to access the wsdl from my local desktop like this - endpoint?wsdl and works perfectly fine.

How can I access this when deployed in a remote server? What endpoint should it be given? Can it contain localhost and port as it is?

Do I need to refer the context path of the web app? Its a little bit confusing...Can someone help pls?

Comment: When deploying in a JavaEE web container, use `servlet` inbound endpoints, not `http` ones, otherwise you start a second web server! Better use the one provided by the JavaEE container.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to localhost so it'll only work on the machine it's running. You can bind to all interfaces using 0.0.0.0 and the access it remotely using the machine's IP address or domain name.

Comment: Thanks Tracy. Should I specify the endpoint as http://0.0.0.0:7001/helloService? Can the ipaddress remain as 0.0.0.0 for all environments (dev/uat/prod). To access this endpoint, is it required to mention the port name? Or domain name alone is enough? Pls help

Comment: Yes. If you use 0.0.0.0 it will bind to every IP on the machine including localhost (127.0.0.1). Alternatively you could specify the actual IP address on every machine.